# Basic variable understanding

Tags: python, variables, scope

What will the following code print?

```
def obfuscation_station():
    def mysterious_inner_function():
        x = 5
        def doubly_mysterious(x):
            return 10 / x
        return doubly_mysterious(2)
    return 10*mysterious_inner_function()


print(obfuscation_station())
```

The answer is 50.0 and I do not understand why exactly the answer is a float and not an int. And what can I code that I can also see that this 50.0 is a float? I tried type and isinstance but I can't make it work.

Comment: `/` always returns a `float`, even if both arguments are `int`s.

Comment: The answer changed between Python 2.7 and Python 3.0.

Comment: "I can't make it work" isn't useful information unless you show us the code you tried.

Comment: All these nested functions seem to have **nothing** to do with your question. You could have just used asked "why is `10/2 * 10` giving me `50.0`?

Answer (score 0):

Division returns a `float` - and this makes sense. Let's say we wanted to compute `3 / 2`. We know that equals to `1.5`, *a float*. This is why python returns a `float` in your case. However, even though you are getting an integer answer, python doesn't care. It still returns a `float` regardless because it doesn't know whether the result will be a `float` or an `integer` reliably. If you really have a problem with this, just use the `int` function:

```py
def obfuscation_station():
    def mysterious_inner_function():
        x = 5
        def doubly_mysterious(x):
            return 10 / x
        return doubly_mysterious(2)
    return 10*mysterious_inner_function()


print(int(obfuscation_station())) # 50, not 50.0
```

However, if you are expecting to get *non-integer answers* from this function, then you definitely don't want to run `int`, because it always rounds down. Instead, you might want to do `round`, which rounds properly, or just keep it as a `float`.